# ECW support Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ecw

I'm not seeing any support for the ECW format in Mac OS X 10.11. Nothing recent in searches here and the latest on kyngchaos is for 10.9 and doesn't do anything for QGIS 2.12.